# Is it possible to remove all chrome from a browser window (not full screen)

Tags: javascript, css, browser, toolbars

Is it possible to remove all "chrome" from a browser window, without going full-screen (with or without CSS/js) Ala Quicktime modal?

So all you see is the content and the drop shadows no toolbars, not even the close/minimise/minimise toolbar.

Comment: Are you looking for html5 full screen api?

Comment: Nope. Don't want to maximise "fullscreen" - just to open a new-window without any toolbars

Comment: Sadly not. RIP http://turnofftheinternet.com/, you were fun while you lasted!

Comment: There are good reasons why you might want to do this. Assuming that I'd want to do it willy nilly, without knowledge of the implications, is enormously arrogant of you. You're also assuming your knowledge of accessibility and usablilty is better than mine too. Thanks for adding nothing but sarcasm. It was really helpful.

Comment: @liamcrean It's not a question of whether *you* want to do it willy-nilly. If it were possible, it *will* be abused by malicious people.

Comment: I don't dispute it. In fact I want to push against the idea myself, but first I needed to find out what was possible. Toolbar-less with basic 'chrome' being the compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.

You can open a new window with *some* chrome removed using the `strWindowFeatures` features of [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open), but you've never been able to remove the title bar and more features set to Always On by browsers as an anti-phishing measure.

You could get something similar to what you are asking for by just using an iframe in an existing page. Obviously, it won't be free floating.

Comment: This is what I expected. Thanks. It was for a web-app video-player that was to work independently for an networked organisation. We didn't really want to have to build an app for it, so thought making it tool-bar-free would make it feel more native and give us control over the entire UI. Thanks all the same.